# Map string formatting to a list of numbers

Tags: python

Is there a way to map some thing like `".2f" % (num)` to a list of numbers using the map function?

Normally to print a list of numbers I would do something like the following:

```
>>> a = [1.003,2.004,3.005]
>>> print " ".join(map(str, a))
1.003 2.004 3.005
```

But what would I put in place of the underscores to get the desired output below?

```
>>> print " ".join(map(____, a))
1.00 2.00 3.01
```

**Edit**

To clarify, the rounding isn't important. 3.00 works as well.

Comment: You can't get `3.01` for `3.005` using `'%.2f'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a = [1.003,2.004,3.005]
print " ".join(map("{:.2f}".format, a))
```

**Output**

```
1.00 2.00 3.00
```

**Note:** Python, by default, rounds `3.005` to `3.00`

Answer (score 2):

For format a list as described, use list comprehension

```
>>> print " ".join("%.2f" % n for n in a)
```

Or, if you really want to use map:

```
>>> print " ".join(map((lambda n: "%.2f" % n), a))
```

As noted, though, there are some peculiarities with rounding off floats.  See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more info.

If you really want accurate rounding off, you can acheive this with [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), e.g.:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> a = ['1.003', '2.004', '3.005']
>>> ctx = decimal.Context(prec=3, rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> print " ".join(str(ctx.create_decimal(n)) for n in a)
['1.00', '2.00', '3.01']
```

However this means working with strings rather than floats as input.

Comment: I am trying second one but it give exception `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @thefourtheye I assumed that the question was about how to concatenate formatted strings rather than about the perculiarities of floating point calculations

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sorry, typo - I missed some brackets.  Answer updated.

Comment: No just `" ".join(map(lambda n: "%.2f" % n, a))` is correct I forgot to write `%` in string  formating

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to generate your strings and print them, but as Ashwini Chaudhary said in the comments, you can't get 3.01 for 3.005 using the string format '.2f'

```
a = [1.003,2.004,3.005]
b = ' '.join(['{:.2f}'.format(num) for num in a])
print(b) # 1.00 2.00 3.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good solutions here. But they don't seem to meet your expected output. This is because of the way round function deals with floats (read the [Note in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)). The solution is to use decimals for an accurate rounding:

```
from decimal import *
" ".join(map(lambda x: str(Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)), a))
# '1.00 2.00 3.01'
```

Answer (score 0):

to get a 'round up %.2f' you can add 0.001 to your input

```
a = [1.003, 2.004, 3.005]
# add 0.001 to round up
print(' '.join(map('{:.2f}'.format, [x + 0.001 for x in a])))
1.00 2.00 3.01
```

so for example, 0.005 --> 0.006 --> 0.01

the `[x + 0.001 for x in a]` part is called 'list comprehension'

im pretty sure, this is faster than using the decimal module

Answer (score 0):

```
"%.2f "*3 % tuple(a)
'1.00 2.00 3.00 '
```

Answer (score 0):

a= [1.003,2.004,3.005]
x = ' '.join(map(str,(list(map('{: .2f}'.format, a)))))
print(x)
1.00  2.00  3.00